# How to separate single column in to columns of database record in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a database table in sql server 2008, the table has a column balls with 20 balls as an example. i want to divide the balls in to red and non red color balls in in a separate columns . i.e 5 red balls in a column, in another and 15 black balls in another column.

All the balls are contain in a single column of a table previously . My query is as below

```
;with r as 
(
SELECT [balls] FROM [balls_table]
)
SELECT (SELECT balls
FROM [balls_table]
WHERE color LIKE '%red%') a,
(SELECT balls
FROM [balls_table]. 
WHERE color NOT LIKE '%red%') as b
 FROM r
```

I thought i can select the whole balls first, and then select red and non red from the first select as i did above. The above query return an exception saying a sub query returns more one one record. Pls , any help would be appreciated

Comment: You have to combine the two columns by e.g. a unique number. You also have to think of whether the 5 balls should be at the beginning of your new table, at the end, spread evenly and so on. What value do you want to show if there is no red ball in a row, but a black ball?

Comment: @alzaimar, each sub query above returns a subsequent number of records which i want to be in a separate columns. I am not combining the columns , thats what confused me more. I though it suppose be okay that way

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can do as follows - get the result with 20 rows but have two columns (isred and isnotred which will contain 1 in case if ball red or not red and 0 otherwise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using CASE WHEN like this :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN color LIKE '%red%' THEN [balls] ELSE NULL END AS RedBalls,
       CASE WHEN color NOT LIKE '%red%' THEN [balls] ELSE NULL END AS NonRedBalls
FROM [balls_table]
```

You can get total red and non red balls by SUM like below :

```
SELECT SUM(RedBalls) AS RedBalls , SUM(NonRedBalls) AS NonRedBalls
FROM
(
SELECT CASE WHEN color LIKE '%red%' THEN [balls] ELSE NULL END AS RedBalls,
       CASE WHEN color NOT LIKE '%red%' THEN [balls] ELSE NULL END AS NonRedBalls
FROM [balls_table]
) tt
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/69843/6)

Comment: Thanks. Howver,to get the total , i had to use Then 1 else 0. When i use when red [balls] else 0, i get a conversion error.

Comment: balls field is numeric or varchar ? if varchar then you need to convert it to numiric using CAST() or CONVERT() function

Comment: Yah thank you sir.Now i am trying to see if i can achieve the two in a single query. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select
CASE WHEN color = 'Red' THEN Color ELSE NULL END As Color1,
CASE WHEN color <> 'Red' THEN Color ELSE NULL END As Color2
from balls
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5b4f/3)